# Cruise Control.NET with SVN

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to configure the latest version of Cruise Control with SVN and looking for the simple steps to do the same. Not able to make out much from [this](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Subversion+Source+Control+Block). Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? A connexion issue ? A timeout ? Authorization issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom block like this:

```
<cb:define name="svn">
   <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkUrl>$(url)</trunkUrl>
      <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe</executable>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>secret</password>
      <workingDirectory>$(workingCopy)</workingDirectory>
      <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
   </sourcecontrol>
</cb:define>
```

(just put it somewhere at the beginning directly under the root node)

Then I can use this in a project like this:

```
<project name="YourProject">
    <cb:svn url="https://yourserver/svn/yourproject/trunk/" workingCopy="C:\src\yourproject"/>
    ...
```

This way I do not need to repeat the subversion configuration all the time.